# Make a PHP script to to make a post draft publish like wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I don't know the appropriate words to describe my question.

But I want to know if there is some tutorial about how wordpress save publish update there posts.

As I am working on a project and I am doing my best to accomplish this but I am unable to get 100% result.

For example I successfully save any post and publish for one time then there are many problems when I try to update a published post.

I also facilitate users to preview there post with current changes.

How can I do all these tasks perfectly.

In-short is wordpress's post method the right thing that I want.

Comment: Wordpress is written in PHP and you can look at its code.

Comment: Please add more specific examples of the problems you are having. I am unclear on if you mean core post/publish functionality in WP or if you are trying to emulate the functionality via custom PHP for wordpress.

Comment: hi Josh i am not working in wordpress. But i need wp post,publish,save functionality in my custom php project.

Answer (score 2):

Need more information to understand what problem you are facing. Still i will try to answer your question.

When we are using wordpress, it save it's content (post, page or whatever other content you add/change) in a mysql server using php. If you are using php and mysql (==mysqli), then you can do same as wordpres.

When you first create a post on wordpress, it save one copy on mysql database. when you open that post to edit again, it create another copy of same post includes new edit/changes you mad. the new copy become the valid copy and wordpress save old copy as previous version, it call revision. you call read details here: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions

**How does view functionality work?** "I also facilitate users to preview there post with current changes."
when you edit a file, but haven't save content yet, wordpress will save content as a special revision (check the wordpress revision link). view link will have id of that special revision and you can see that update unsaved content with that link.

**How does autosave work?**
Using ajax/jquery $.post - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
When you editing the post, wordpress save content using ajax/jquery $.post method which doesn't require refresh of the page, so you can still be on the page and continue your editing without interepting.

Please let me know if i miss something.
Sorry for my broken english, not native english speaker.